# Web page that loads content first, then beautifies it by deferred-loading hi res image swap-ins?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, retina-display, progressive-enhancement, deferred-loading

I have made a site that looks acceptable and strikes a balance between having a reasonable load time and not overly-compressing the JPEG images. One concern is that there is a 100% stretching full-screen background, which while it looks fine on 13-inch display, could spell ugliness on something like a 5K retina display. I can't justify making mobile users suffer by serving them huge images though. What I'm looking for is a "lazy loader" or "deferred loader" that will detect display size and pixel density (retina vs non-retina) and serve the highest quality images possible - but only after all of the site content has been loaded using moderately compressed images and is in a browsable state. If possible I would like for the hi-res swap-in images to do a fade-in transition as they overlay and replace the default-res ones. And I would like for it to be clear to the user that the page has loaded and is ready to interact with, meaning no progress bar indicating that content is not finished downloading.

Goals / Steps

1. Quickly load the basic page with moderately compressed images. The page can now be interacted with and doesn't look terrible. When search engines spider the page it should be considered fully loaded at this stage, otherwise page rank could suffer.
2. Check the device display size and pixel density to know what resolution images to swap in.
3. Serve the images in the appropriate resolution but keep them hidden until they are fully loaded and ready to be faded in.
4. Fade the hi-res images in. (Fade-in does not need to be synchronized across images, each can fade in over its low-res counterpart as it becomes ready)

Am I asking for a miracle? Should I just give up and stick with mediocre somewhat compressed images? I can't be the only one wanting to do this, so I'm trying to find out what techniques are available.

I have found bits and pieces of answers around the web, but nowhere have I seen a solution that ties it all together. There appears to be no "best practice" for handling this, which is surprising. I know that apple.com serves retina images if you view their site on a retina device, but I have no idea how they do it ([Example: store photo](http://www.apple.com/cn/retail/pudong/)). I have found a script that lazy loads retina images (on jsfiddle, so I'm not going to link and clutter this post with code), but it's triggered by scrolling and I don't know how to rework the code to load them after the page content instead. Here's [another lazy loader](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) that uses jQuery although I haven't been able to get it to work for me, and again I don't know how I could make it load after the page content, nor do I know how so make the images fade in over existing low-res ones, nor do I know how to incorporate retina display detection.

Is there any hope for someone without much javascript knowledge to be able to pull this off using some existing code, or should I continue my meager existence in Lowres Land?

Edit: I think a more relevant term than "lazy loading" might be "deferred loading". I'm finding that lazy loading usually is in reference to content that renders while scrolling down a page. I have refined my search. Will post any findings here. I am currently reading [this](http://24ways.org/2010/speed-up-your-site-with-delayed-content), but have not digested it all yet.

Edit2: I think jQuery's deferred and fadeIn together, (with media queries for retina) may hold the answer. I found [an example](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1) in the jQuery documentation that looks like a variation of what I want.
But I am in way over my head as far as tying this all together.

Comment: Use CSS and media queries to apply the appropriate background image. This is covered is about a million other questions.

Comment: Typical stackoverflow reply. It's not helpful to just state that it's been "asked a million times before". Also you didn't address the part about delaying image loading or applying fade-in transitions. I'm trying to do something more specific than just use media queries to load hi-res images, if you read. Media queries may come into play as part of the solution, but don't be dismissive of my question just because retina display has been discussed before somewhere on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is it possible you could show us what you have tried already?  As it stands, the question is asking for a *best practice* which is outside the scope of Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should really look into [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). This is a lazyloader, which is build on top of the HTML5 responsive images standard (and all polyfills) and also supports swapping low quality images to higher quality images. (This is called low quality image placeholder pattern or short LQIP).

Here is an example for static width images:

```
<img src="low-quality.jpg" data-srcset="normal.jpg 1x, retina.jpg 2x" class="lazyload" />
```

And here is one for adaptive width images:

```
<img src="low-quality.jpg" data-srcset="low-quality.jpg 300w, image-1 480w, image-2.jpg 600w, image-3.jpg 980w" data-sizes="auto" class="lazyload" />
```

Some parts about what you want to do are not clear or not so good.

1. **Your LQIP plan:**
   In case you have a lot of images (more than 6 images on a page for example). I would not use LQIP for all images, but only for crucial ones or none, because if you add a lot of images, they still need to be downloaded and the browser can only handle 6 requests at once. This means you will not gain too much performance if you gather your page with a lot of small images. In that case it is much better to not download images at all and only load the images, which are in view as soon as possible.
2. **Images after content:**
   I'm not really sure whether I understand this right. Normal images are content and from a perceived performance perspective images are the [most important parts of a page](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/26/i/). So what other content are you loading? Or what other content is currently loaded after your images? Do you load your content with AJAX? It is crucial to load visible images as fast as possible. And if you trigger an image download via JS it is already hidden from the [preload parser](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/big-bad-preloader/), even if you start it right away, which means it is already deferred in the browser's download queue. Additionally if you have 1-3 images in view and about 10 outside of view, it is already great improvement to download only those 1-3 images.

All this said, in case you want to further delay loading even visible images you can do so by simple adding the class `lazyload` after some time or even after the `onload` event.

Here an example:

```
<img src="low-quality.jpg" data-srcset="low-quality.jpg 300w, image-1 480w, image-2.jpg 600w, image-3.jpg 980w" data-sizes="auto" class="big-bg" />
```

And here the JS:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
     $('.big-bg').addClass('lazyload');
});
```

And here is a full example which also includes a simple transition effect using CSS:
http://embed.plnkr.co/9tii4RTjYL2CpiQdXlbn/preview

Comment: Very helpful! LQIP. lazySizes. Got it. I think this may be the solution and I expect to know for sure once I test it. I don't load my content with AJAX. Sorry if I was unclear - not sure which part to elaborate more on, but I won't need to lazy load more than 6 images. I get what you mean that images are content. Some however are backgrounds - not a high priority for the user. Most are at a resolution/compression that is a good tradeoff between load time and quality - but isn't amazing quality. So I want to get the best of both. lazySizes + your "on load" trick looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [progressive jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) as I think it fits your use case. Even for large images, the progressive jpeg will provide a good experience as it loads.

Also rather than using media queries to determine image size you should try to utilize [`srcset`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-img-srcset) property. With `srcset` the browser will do the heavy lifting in determining which imageurl is best fit for the client.

Although it currently has limited [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) available.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Progressive JPEG does not accomplish the goal because it will still load a large image in the end. Bad news for mobile users, and bad news for the Google page rank because of increased load time. I am looking into srcset now. Does "This is no longer being developed as a separate specification" mean something else has replaced this spec? As for polyfill, I am looking at that too, although it seems it does not fallback gracefully if javascript is disabled(?)

Comment: @Mentalist updated the srcset link. Previous link in turn pointed to another link. I think they had just stopped documenting on that specific link - still supporting as far as I know.  Would mobile users be affected as I figured you would load a smaller image for those clients?

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, I want the basic (lossy compression, low-res) images to load first for everyone and just get the page loaded and ready to interact with. Then I want the hi-res versions to be loaded and once loaded fade in slowly, replacing the low-res ones. It should be a smooth transition, not a jerky one, so that users won't feel something went wrong. And finally, when serving the hi-res images it should detect and account for users on devices of higher pixel density (retina).

Comment: @Mentalist thanks for the clarification. I think what you had suggested with fadeIn (based on your page load event) works. You're basically doing your own version of progressive jpeg. If at the start of the fadeIn the high res images (blurred) looks just like the low res it should make for a nice transition as it appears fully.

Comment: There are two issues with progressive JPEG though. 1. The page can't be counted as "loaded" by browsers or search engine spiders until those heavy images are loaded. Users will see a progress bar. Google will think your page is too heavy and penalize you. 2. Progressive JPEG just doesn't look so smooth. It pulls users' attention away from the site and makes them think "my image is still loading". It starts as super-chunky block noise and refines in passes (think 90's crime drama security cam "Enhance!") and while this is happening it is an eyesore and a distraction.

Comment: @Mentalist to clarify, when I said "progressive jpeg" I didn't mean the actual format but rather the technique you described that simulates a similar behavior. 1) You load low res images 2) At some time where it doesn't affect your site speed you fetch the high res images 3) when ready have the high res images replace low res while being blurred (im thinking maybe some kind of overlay over them to make them look like the low res - should idealy be transparent to user - no flash) 4) slowly unblur the overlay until user sees the high res image. A "fake/simulated" version of "progressive jpeg".